# Installing jBPM on Linux

Tags: linux, jboss, jbpm

I have been using the following to set up a jBPM/JBoss server on a remote machine (linux)

http://docs.jboss.org/jbpm/v5.1/userguide/ch03.html

The above linked worked fine locally on my windows box, without any hitches.  However, I am having numerous errors with starting/shutting-down the server, and having the drools-guvnor page run completely (or any other than the JBoss AS splash page on localhost:8080).  Should this be working fine on linux as well, or are there any other references that I can seek?  Also, I have no desire to install eclipse, just to get the jBPM designer going.

Or am I better off attempting to load jBPM into a separate JBoss install?

Running Red Hate Enterprise Linux Server release 5.8

Thank you for your time

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was unable to get the jBPM installer demo (packaged with jboss) to work.  Instead I did a separate installation of jBPM and JBoss and set the JBoss home in the build.xml file.  Then performed the individual installation of guvnor and designer using

ant install.guvnor.into.jboss
ant install.designer.into.jboss

Still having errors, but the designer/guvnor are up and running, now it is a database problem :(